# Cómo comprobar que el contenido de un string es exactamente el que quiero

Tags: c++, string

Con un número sí sé hacerlo, pero con una palabra no.

Es que no tengo mucho nivel y me faltan herramientas por conocer y no sé cómo funcionan muchas.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Aunque tu pregunta es clara, hubiera estado bien que hubieras mostrado algo de esfuerzo buscando la solución por ti mismo, compartiendo el código de lo que has intentado.

Answer (score -1):

Supongo que te refieres a comparar cadenas de caracteres... Para ello debes emplear la función `strncmp`. Esta función se define como:
`int strncmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2, size_t num );`
Donde los parámetros de entrada son las cadenas que quieres comparar, y el número de caracteres a comparar. La función te retorna un `0` si las cadenas que estás comparando son iguales.

Un código de ejemplo:

```
/* strncmp example */
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  char str[][5] = { "R2D2" , "C3PO" , "R2A6" };
  int n;

  cout << "Looking for R2 astromech droids..." << endl;
  for (n=0 ; n<3 ; n++)
    if (strncmp (str[n],"R2xx",2) == 0)
    {
      cout << "found " << str[n] << endl;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

En este ejemplo estás comparando la cadena "R2xx", pero tan sólo sus dos primeros caracteres, es decir, estás buscando si en lo que introduces alguno de ellos comienza por "R2".
El programa muestra lo siguiente:

```
Looking for R2 astromech droids...
found R2D2
found R2A6
```

Answer (score -1):

Para ello tienes [`string::compare()`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::string cadena1 ("hola");
  std::string cadena2 ("adios");
  std::string cadena3 ("hola");

  if (cadena1.compare(cadena2) == 0) {
    std::cout << cadena1 << " es igual a " << cadena2 << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << cadena1 << " NO es igual a " << cadena2 << std::endl;
  }
  if (cadena1.compare(cadena3) == 0) {
    std::cout << cadena1 << " es igual a " << cadena3 << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << cadena1 << " NO es igual a " << cadena3 << std::endl;
  }
  if (cadena2.compare("adios") == 0) {
    std::cout << cadena2 << " es igual a adios" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << cadena2 << " NO es igual a adios" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

El resultado de la ejecución será:

```
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -o prueba prueba.cpp
$ ./prueba
hola NO es igual a adios
hola es igual a hola
adios es igual a adios
```

Comment: Agradecería un comentario acompañando al -1 indicando en qué falla la respuesta o en qué puede mejorar. Gracias.